# File "liblinphone-armeabi-v7a.so" error when update Linphone

Tags: android, linphone, linphone-sdk

> /data/app/appname-2/lib/arm/liblinphone-armeabi-v7a.so has text
>   relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening.
>   Please fix.

When I update Linphone library, I get this message and crash my application. Who had the same problem like me?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like one of the codecs (AMRWB) causes that.

The Manifest file of linphone-android shows

```
...
BUILD_AMRWB=0 # Has text relocation issue, don't use when targetting API 23 for now
...
```

The param `BUILD_NON_FREE_CODECS` is defined like that:

```
ifeq ($(BUILD_NON_FREE_CODECS), 0)
BUILD_OPENH264=0
ENABLE_OPENH264_DECODER=0
BUILD_AMRNB=0
BUILD_AMRWB=0
BUILD_G729=0
BUILD_X264=0
endif
```

So I was able to avoid that error you metioned (*liblinphone-armeabi-v7a.so has text relocations*) by doing:

```
$ make BUILD_NON_FREE_CODECS=0
$ make liblinphone-android-sdk BUILD_NON_FREE_CODECS=0
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. Let me check it. :)